# How do I standardise dates in a data frame column?

Tags: r

I have a data frame where one of the columns contains dates. The dates appear in 2 formats in the column:

1. Wednesday, March 16, 2023
2. Wed, Mar 16 2023

For the output I need to produce, all the dates in the column have to follow the smae format.

The best way I have been able to do this has been to run a for loop but that has drastically increased the run time due to volume of data.

Comment: `lubridate::mdy(c("Wednesday, March 16, 2023", "Wed, Mar 16 2023"))`

Comment: You don't have a column that contains dates.  You have a column of character strings that (you hope) represent dates.  The difference is critical.